# Difference between Factory vs ObjectManager while instance object

Tags: magento2, factory

I have some confusion while use Factory pattern vs new instance object.

What difference between them?

`$object = objectManager->create()` vs `objectManager->create('ObjectFactory')`

what benefits in cases when create object by Factory.

This thread may be large but I need core team members to help me clearly minds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use `$objectManager` directly because it takes control from clients of your code and leads to higher code coupling

We split all objects to two groups: injectables & non-injectables.

`Injectables` - all services, mostly stateless classes like FrontController or EventManager should be requested in object constructors.

`Non-Injectables` - all entities, mostly stateful objects like Product or Category should be created through Factories. And Factories should be requested in constructors.

You can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#dep-inj-mod-type-life-mgmt

Comment: Sometime i got null object while use factory. It related to shared object create?

Comment: What do you mean by null object? Is it null value?

Comment: i request model factory from block by ->create('id') like this. Results get null. May be i am doing wrong somewhere

Comment: I have a question. I have a model, how to get id of this model use Factory, I should get id in model or model resourceCollection. Magento 2 use getId and getById somewhere, it make me some confusing

Comment: to create a model you use $modelFactory->create(); To load a Model directly from a Factory you can use $modelFactory->create()->load($id); To get the ID of a Model you use $model->getId(); The getById($id) is typical for Repositories which can also create you modelinstancens like $modelRepository->getById($id)